# Kendo Grid (Angular 2+) Can't filter number Column

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, filtering

Using the official grid filtering example from Kendo [Plunker link](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/#), If I enable the filter for the ProductID field then the filter does not work and I see the following error in console. Basically, none of the numbered column filter is working. However if the data type is string it works.

**ERROR:**

```
ERROR TypeError: (d.ProductID || "").toLowerCase is not a function
    at eval (eval at t.compileFilter (VM1859 kendo-data-query.js:NaN), <anonymous>:3:29)
    at Object.t.count (VM1859 kendo-data-query.js:1)
    at Object.t.process (VM1859 kendo-data-query.js:1)
    at AppComponent.dataStateChange (VM1970 app.component.ts!transpiled:22)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (VM1971 AppComponent.ngfactory.js:23)
    at handleEvent (VM856 core.umd.js:12108)
    at callWithDebugContext (VM856 core.umd.js:13567)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (VM856 core.umd.js:13155)
    at dispatchEvent (VM856 core.umd.js:8720)
    at eval (VM856 core.umd.js:10882)
```

Comment: Currently I did a workaround by casting the datatype to string. But this bug need to be fixed by Kendo Team.

Answer (score 1):

This throws an error, if `d.ProductID` is neither `null`, `undefined` nor of type `string`, e.g. if `d.ProductID = 12`. I'm assuming in your example the id is of type number.

I'm not familiar with this library, but if you look at the examples, they do have a filter for numeric values:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" width="180" filter="numeric" format="{0:c}">
```

An id should be represented as a string and not an integer though. As a rule of thumb, an integer should only be used, if arithmetic operations make sense; e.g. if you can add two instances. Ids are names, even if they are represented by numbers. (Just like phone numbers). Hence, you should use a string representation here.

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo Grid filtering uses string as default. 
You need to specify the type of value in the filter. 
i.e. :  filter="date",  filter="numeric"